# Wait for all Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a little problem with Threads in this code..

I just want to run a lot of tasks together, and continue when all of them finish.

```
while (true)
{
    //   Run tasks together:
    foreach (object T in objectsList)
    {
        if (T.something>0)
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => T.RunObject());
            task.ContinueWith(delegate { ChangeObject(T, 1); }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
    }
    //   <-- Here I want to wait for all the task to be finish.
    //   I know its task.Wait() but how to waitAll()?
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(this.GetNextTime()); 
    var RefreshObjects = new Task(loadObjectsList); RefreshObjects .Start(); RefreshObjects.Wait();
}
```

I don't know how many objects will be in `objectsList` and I don't know if `T.something` will be > 0.
so I can't just use:

```
Task[] Tasks = new Task[objectsList.count()]
for (int T=0; T<objectsList.count(); ++T)
{
    if (objectsList[T].something>0)
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectsList[T].RunObject());
        task.ContinueWith(delegate { ChangeObject(objectsList[T], 1); }, ...);
}
Task.WaitAll(Tasks);
```

Because `Tasks` will contains nulls when `objectsList[T].something!>0`...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch the condition and create a List of tasks only for the objects which matches your criteria.

```
var tasks = objectsList
            .Where(x => x.Something() > 0)
            .Select(x => {
                            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => x.RunObject());
                            task.ContinueWith(t => ChangeObject(....));
                            return task;
                         })
            .ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Your code sample just waits for `RunObject()`to complete! If this is desired skip the rest of my answer. If you want to wait for the continuation to complete, too you can use this

```
var tasks = objectsList
            .Where(x => x.Something() > 0)
            .Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => x.RunObject()).ContinueWith(t => ChangeObject(....)))
            .ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

because `ContinueWith` generates a new Task.

Comment: You can easily avoid making the `select` a statement delegate by calling `ContinueWith` on the task without assigning it to a varaible

Comment: Depends.. if he wants to wait for the continuation to complete, too he can. If he just wants for the initial task to complete he has to go with the statement.

Comment: Realy helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `objectsList` implements IEnumerable, (as an array does), 
(And there are less than 64 objects in the list), you can use this:

```
public delegate void SyncDelegatesInParallelDelegate<in T>(T item);
public static class ParallelLinqExtensions
{
    public static void SyncDelegatesInParallel<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> list, 
        SyncDelegatesInParallelDelegate<T> action)
    {
        var foundCriticalException = false;
        Exception exception = null;
        var waitHndls = new List<WaitHandle>();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            // Temp copy of session for modified closure
            var localItem = item;
            var txEvnt = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            // Temp copy of session for closure
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                 depTx =>
                 {
                     try { if (!foundCriticalException) action(localItem); }
                     catch (Exception gX) 
                     { exception = gX; foundCriticalException = true; }
                     finally { txEvnt.Set(); }
                 }, null);
            waitHndls.Add(txEvnt);
        }
        if (waitHndls.Count > 0) WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHndls.ToArray());
        if (exception != null) throw exception;
    }
}
```

you would call it like this

```
 objectsList.SyncDelegatesInParallel(delegate { ChangeObject(T, 1);});
```

Comment: This won't work if there are more than 64 objects in the objectsList because that is the limit on the number of wait handles.